# JavaFX TreeView is not working in Java 8

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to use this TreeView code in Java 8

http://code.google.com/p/javafx-demos/source/browse/trunk/javafx-demos/src/main/java/com/ezest/javafx/demogallery/treeview/DyanmicTreeView.java?r=81

for some reason I can run the code in Java 7 but when I run it on Java 8 b129 it's not working. Can you help me to find what causes this problem?

This is the result that I get with Java 8:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly doesn't work? As for me it compiles and run smoothly.

Comment: I've used precisely 8b129 for x86 linux.

Comment: I added screenshot. I don't know why but I always get this result.

Comment: There is definitely a change between 7 and 8. In your case it is clear that in 8 the root item doesn't receive branchExpanded event because it is empty (has no children). Thus according to your algorithm it will remain empty forever. As for me it is unlikely a bug and you better populate the root item first.

Comment: Can you help me to fix this please?

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other solution which you can propose?

Comment: If you want to wait until the event comes then you may create some tree items without data and then reset the root when the expansion occurs with correct data. See example: http://pastebin.com/htyY8EJj